# Search between multiple numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----+
| Size from | Size till | Price From | Price Till | Product ID |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----+
|        50 |        52 |       10.0 |       15.0 |  1 |
|        50 |        52 |       16.0 |       20.0 |  2 |
|        48 |        50 |       12.0 |       16.0 |  3 |
|        50 |        52 |        8.0 |        9.0 |  4 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----+
```

Now in my main table I only have 2 rows:
A1 = Size, B1 = Price, *C1 = Result product ID*

A1 and B1 get filled out by my self.

I have problems finding the correct formula to find the Product ID. 
I want to search the ID there the Size is between "Size from", "Size till" and the Price between "Price From", "Price Till".
At the moment I did it with multiple `IF(A1=<Table2!A1 & A1=>Table2!A2 & B2 ...`

This works as long as I dont have more values, actually I want to include more parameters which would result in a too long function. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your Query Criteria based Lookup Formula is required, which checks the Criteria within the Range.**

To solve the issue I've used your sample Data. Check it below.

[image]

**The Data Range is, A54:E57.**

**Criteria Range is, A62:B62.**

**Criteria are  Size 49 & Price 15**

Formula is in Cell **D62**.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$54:$A$57<=A62)/($B$54:$B$57>=A62)/($C$54:$C$57<=B62)/($D$54:$D$57>=B62),($E$54:$E$57))
```

**NB:** Adjust the Data Range as per your need.

Comment: I have no clue for what the number 2 is as search criteria. But it works like a charm big thanks.

Comment: If you are talking about 2,1/(A54:A57<=A62) in the formula, actually it calculates an array of #DIV/0!'s, Since we're trying to match 2 ,which is larger than any of the calculated numeric values so, LOOKUP function ignores the errors and returns the value associated with the
LAST numeric item in the array.

Comment: So If I want to match 3 parameters I would have to change it to `3,1/(A54:A57<=A62....` ?

Comment: No, actually it checks  each of the comparisons  for larger value between <= or >= .

Comment: Ok, ty I think I understood now.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how the values of the cells in the A column and B column affect what the product ID is. What characteristics affect the product ID in all cases?

For example, if the product ID is the A multiplied by B plus a certain constant, you can write a formula like:

`=$A1*$B1+42` for example does this. You can click the corner of a cell, and drag to the cells below to copy the formula to the next rows. (Again, you'll have to change this to suit your needs, I don't know your exact situation.) In programming terms, it's the difference between doing:

```
if (x == 0) y = 3;
if (x == 1) y = 4;
if (x == 2) y = 5;
```

...and doing...

```
y = x + 3;
```

I can't give a complete formula and solve your problem without knowing the exact formula, but creating these formulas (and programming) is often about pattern recognition. I can't give a more specific answer without more specific information.

Comment: Sry more clearified: I want to search the ID there the Size is between "Size from", "Size till" and the Price between "Price From", "Price Till".